# Netezza conditionally count one record per ID

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm new to Netezza and need to count the number of IDs that have a non-zero key. My KEY is a transaction type, and I want to return a count of the IDs that have had any transaction. Basically I want a count of all UIDs which have a non-zero key.

My data:

```
SRC UID KEY ...
A   118 3   ...
A   517 0   ...
A   517 1   ...
A   517 4   ...
B   623 4   ...
C   972 0   ...
C   972 0   ...
```

What I want to return:

```
SOURCE  UIDs    UIDs_W_TRANS
A       2       2
B       1       1
C       1       0
```

Here's my code:

```
SELECT
    SRC AS SOURCE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(UID)) AS UIDs,
    SUM(CASE WHEN KEY = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1) AS UIDs_W_TRANS

FROM
    DATABASE

GROUP BY
    UID,
    SOURCE
```

What I'm getting back is

```
SOURCE  UIDs    UIDs_W_TRANS
A       2       3
B       1       1
C       1       0
```

You can see that my query is counting every non-zero KEY. I've tried a number of variations on the above query, but nothing has gotten me closer. How can I only count 1 non-zero KEY per UID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a conditional `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT SRC AS SOURCE,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(UID)) AS UIDs,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN KEY <> 0 THEN UID END) AS UIDs_W_TRANS
FROM DATABASE
GROUP BY SOURCE
```

Comment: Wow, what a succinct way to solve this. In my results, it looks to me like this is giving a count of the UIDs with no transactions. I think I want `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN KEY != 0 THEN UID END) AS UIDs_W_TRANS`. Also, can you help me understand why I don't need an ELSE clause in this statement?

Comment: @Lenwood . . . Yes, it should be `<> 0` rather than `= 0`.